# How to order results when using typeahead from ngx-bootstrap?

Tags: bootstrap-4, typeahead, ngx-bootstrap

I am using customTemplate for my typeahead which has three fields

`({{model.number}}-{{model.city}}-{{model.state}})`

using the `number` as the `typeaheadOptionField`, I see there is `typeaheadGroupField` available which I use on the number field .... I would like to know is there anyway in which I can `order` the result based on the `city` field?

```
<ng-template #customCapTemplate let-model="item" let-index="index">
   <h5>{{model.code}}-{{model.city}}-{{model.prov}}</h5>
</ng-template>
<input name="colCap" [typeahead]="capList" typeaheadGroupField="code" 
    typeaheadOptionField="code" [typeaheadItemTemplate]="customCapTemplate" class="form-control">
```

currently it is showing the result like this 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Using `typeaheadGroupField` should give you subheaders and group items under each subheader.

The other approach you can take is to first order "capList" before it goes into the ngx-bootstrap typeahead.

Good luck!